# Default value of the entity attribute

Tags: outsystems

I have a entity attribute in the other appliaction which I am referening in my applicaton whose default value is CurrDate(). So when I am using this antity in to my application it automatically shows the currDate.. But I want to set  date to a input field in to my application which refers  to the entity to CurrDate()+3... How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are either using an Aggregate to fetch data, or using a variable with the data type of that entity.

Either way, on the Preparation use an assign to change the value of that field to

```
AddDays(CurrDate(),3)
```